# Receive Callback

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

I want to implement an Asychronous Server Socket. For that I was looking into the Microsoft Docs. And there's something I don't understand.

There's an Callback Function Call `ReceiveCallback`. And as I do understand this function is called, each time a message is received. But why we do check if `bytesRead > 0` ? That would mean that no message was received, and if no message was received the callback function isn't called. As result I never get in the `else condition` and my `response` is never set...

```
private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar )
{  
    try {  
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket   
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;  
        Socket client = state.workSocket;  

        // Read data from the remote device.  
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);  

        if (bytesRead > 0) 
        {  
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));  

            // Get the rest of the data.  
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0, ReceiveCallback, state);  
        } else 
        {  
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  
            if (state.sb.Length > 1) {  
                response = state.sb.ToString();  
            }  
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.  
            receiveDone.Set();  
        }  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
    }  
}
```

Comment: My guess is you lifted this code from an example where the the other end sends data and then closes the connection, triggering the else condition. When the remote end closes the connection, you'll read 0 bytes. From [Socket.EndReceive()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.endreceive?view=netframework-4.8) "If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received, the EndReceive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes."

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks!

So, then you can maybe help me with my next question. 
Is it in common use to close the connection after sending a message?
Because I am receiving xml formatted messages from a device. In case the device doesn't close the connection after sending a message, how do I handle this?

Comment: No, it's not common. It's how HTTP operates among other things, but it sounds like you want to maintain an open connection. The way you should handle that is with [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! That's very helpful.